# /usr/local/bin doesn't exist when trying to add symlink for SublimeText3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, macos-sierra, iterm2

I have been researching this question for 2 hours now and have done everything in all of the answers for creating a symlink for SublimeText3 in macOS Sierra using iTerm2. I have tried all of the following:

1. input:   `ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl` 
   returns: `ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory`
2. input: `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl`   
   returns: `ln: /Users/david/bin/subl: No such file or directory`
3. I have tried creating /usr/local/bin/subl and then executing the above commands but when I use mkdir /usr/local/bin it returns File exists but when I try to run the ln command, I get the same return as examples 1 and 2.
4. In usr/local it shows: bin       remotedesktop but when I try cd bin it returns -bash: cd: bin: No such file or directory and when I look for it in Finder it I get the following error message:  The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “bin” can’t be found.

Here is my $PATH: echo $PATH
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I'm hoping someone can either help me or point in the direction of an answer I missed, because so far none of the answers have worked for me.

When I ran  `echo b | xxd` 
this was the result:
`00000000: 486f 6d65 6272 6577 2062 696e 206c 6962  Homebrew bin lib

00000010: 2073 6269 6e0a                            sbin.`

Results of running:  ls -l /usr/local | cat -vet | pbcopy
total 0$
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   wheel   68 Sep  8 22:04 Cellar$
drwxrwxr-x  2 david  admin   68 Sep  8 22:04 Frameworks$
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   wheel   68 Sep  8 22:04 Homebrew$
drwxrwxr-x  3 david  admin  102 Sep  9 00:14 bin$
drwxrwxr-x  2 david  admin   68 Sep  8 22:04 etc$
drwxrwxr-x  2 david  admin   68 Sep  8 22:04 include$
drwxrwxr-x  2 david  admin   68 Sep  8 22:04 lib$
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   wheel   68 Sep  8 22:04 opt$
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   wheel  102 Jun 12 17:38 remotedesktop$
drwxrwxr-x  2 david  admin   68 Sep  8 22:04 sbin$
drwxrwxr-x  3 david  admin  102 Sep  8 22:04 share$
drwxrwxr-x  2 david  admin   68 Sep  8 22:04 var$

Comment: It sounds like there's an invisible character in the name of the "bin" directory (or maybe a space before/after it). In /usr/local, run the command `echo *b* | xxd` and edit your question to add the output (in code format).

Comment: @GordonDavisson ran the code and added results, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Try `ls -l /usr/local | cat -vet | pbcopy` and paste result into your question.

Comment: Try using a shell variable to be sure you have got the correct path every time... `XX="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`, then you can do `ls -l "$XX"` and use `"$XX"` in your `ln` command knowing it is correct.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nothing happened when used ls -l /usr/local | cat -vet | pbcopy

Comment: It will have put the output into your Clipboard ready for pasting into your question.

Comment: @MarkSetchell ok ran that and added results to question

Comment: @MarkSetchell now when I try to install homebrew i get the following:
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
/usr/local/Homebrew/.git: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q

Comment: @MarkSetchell and when i run brew doctor i get command not found

Comment: Mmm... deleting `/usr/local/bin` was very *"sub-optimal"*! As your **Homebrew** setup is now gone, I would make a directory called `/usr/local/OldHomebrew` and move `/usr/local/Homebrew` and `/usr/local/Cellar` in there before re-installing **Homebrew** afresh.